# Enable / Disable Vue Transitions based on boolean

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In Vue, can I somehow disable a transition-animation, based on a boolean?

So now the animation is enabled:

```
<transition name="fadeUp">
  <div v-if="elIsVisible">
    <p>Foo Bar</p>
  </div>
</transition>
```

But I wish I do something like this:

```
<transition name="fadeUp" animation-enabled="false">
  <div v-if="elIsVisible">
    <p>Foo Bar</p>
  </div>
</transition>
```

Or perhaps a smart work-around?

---

It's a for module-based website (one component per block), where it could be nifty if the user could enable/disable the animation for certain blocks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a workaround, yes. You can skip the CSS detection by setting [`v-bind:css`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks) to `false` on the `<transition>` component.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: () => ({
    show: true,
    animated: true
  })
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

p {
  background-color: beige;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 4px 6px;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <transition name="fade" :css="animated">
    <p v-if="show">Hey, there!</p>
  </transition>

  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="animated" />
    Animated
  </label>
  <button @click="show = !show">Toggle visibility</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can bind `:name` in `<transition>`, which if set to empty, no transition is applied (like when no name is given).

```
<transition :name="transitionName">
  <div v-if="elIsVisible">
    <p>Foo Bar</p>
  </div>
</transition>

<select @change="e => { transitionName = e.target.value }">
  <option
    v-for="transition in ['fadeUp', '']"
    :key="transition"
    :value="transition"
  >
    {{ transition }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Changing name to some other value is actually slightly better than the accepted answer, as this avoids problems with different animation modes (e.g. out-in)